# JAXB - How to specify xml attributes in binding Java Class

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I know to create a JAXB Class to marshal/unmarshall an xml like this

```
<outertag>  
    <innerelement>
        <innerElementDetail1>some value</inner-element-detail1>
    </innerelement>
</outertag>
```

here is the class I created

```
@XmlRootElement(name ="outertag")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class OuterTag {

    @XmlElement(name = "innerelement")
    private List<InnerElement> innerElemements

    public static InnerElement{
        private String innerElementDetail;
        // getters and setters
    }
}
```

If I have to have an attribute on one of the inner elements like this

```
<outertag>  
    <innerelement attribute1="attribute1value">
        <innerElementDetail1>some value</inner-element-detail1>
    </innerelement>
</outertag>
```

how do I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it :

```
@XmlRootElement(name ="outertag")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class OuterTag {

    @XmlElement(name = "innerelement")
    private List<InnerElement> innerElemements

    public static InnerElement{
        @XmlAttribute(name = "attribute1")
        protected String attribute1;

        private String innerElementDetail;
        // getters and setters
    }
}
```